# Carrego todas os dados direto no HTML da página ou acesso mais vezes o banco de dados?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, banco-de-dados, aplicação-web

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto Web para mercado imobiliário. Na página está o espelho de vendas ou a planta baixa do condomínio de casas a ser vendido. Quando o usuário clica em uma das casas da planta, o sistema mostra todas as características dessa casa. Estou em dúvida se é melhor quando carregar a página já colocar no próprio HTML em cada casa ou seja button as informações sobre a casa... Ex:

```
<input id="casa02" type="button" alt="metragem=200m2*preço=R$80000*cor=branca" onclick="abrePopupDetalhes(this.id)"/>
```

...Assim quando clicar nela, o javascript pega o que está no "alt" e mostra no popup. Esse é apenas um exemplo simples, no sistema real são muito mais dados que nesse exemplo.
Ou é melhor buscar no banco de dados as informações a cada clique?

Ou seja, é mais prejudicial o html da página ficar mais pesado ou a página acessar o servidor a cada clique? Estou preocupado com o acesso via celular por causa do 3G.

Comment: O ideal é carregar e mostrar só o que interessa e está visível na tela, como imagens, por exemplo. No caso de imagens, existe um plugin chamado lazyload que só carrega imagens quando ela for rolada na tela. Isso economiza bastante largura de banda e deixa a página mais rápida no carregamento.

Answer (score 0):

Se der pra carregar direto no html seria melhor, principalmente que trabalha com internet movel. A requisição no banco de dados seria grande.

Comment: Obrigado Maick. Eu fiz assim a 1a versão do sistema, mas comecei ficar em dúvida se isso não prejudicaria muito abrir essa página no 3G.